# Remove numbers from result; Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm creating a script that querys websites, and my results end up looking something like this

```
result = "
nameof1stlink
38
nameof2ndlink120
12
nameof3rdlink15
7
nameof4thlin...
k143
43
"
```

Basically, I want to remove the numbers that come after each line of text. That would be easy for me to do in a pattern, but there is the occasional long string that takes up two separate lines. There's also the matter of needing to keep the numbers in the actual text names.

I was thinking of checking each individual line for string length and just removing those w/o 5 or more letters / numbers, but I wasn't sure if that would work, and I wasn't too sure how to do it either.

Any help from you guys would be great.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Would it not be easier to fix the output of the script doing the querying?

Comment: It would be, but probably due to my own limitations, I cannot get beautifulsoup to remove those extra numbers.

Comment: Most likely you could get help on this site for fixing the BeautifulSoup piece. From my perspective that's going to be a better use of your time than trying to solve this particular problem; due to the overlapping line issue.

Comment: It looks like some of your strings end in numbers. How do you deal with a string that wraps and only wraps numbers? For example if `nameof2ndlink120 ` wrapped at `120`. It doesn't seem like there's a way to distinguish those from numbers by themselves.

Comment: assuming the "result" is a string and each text is separated by a new line. If I have understood it correctly, you want to remove only the numbers. You can try splitting the value by space and loop each value and cast to int. If it can't be converted to int, it means its a string and if it can be converted, it is a number. Discard all the numbers and keep the string values.

Comment: there seems to be number in between letters too though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could maybe use regex matching, looking for a link-like string (allowing for newlines) followed by a number and a newline, which you'd want to ignore. Then, to accommodate multi-line links, use simple `str.replace()` to remove any occurrences of the consistent `...\n` that occurs when the link is split across multiple lines.

What I have in mind, given the example you've provided, is this:

```
import re

result = """nameof1stlink
38
nameof2ndlink120
12
nameof3rdlink15
7
nameof4thlin...
k143
43"""

matches = re.findall(r'([A-Za-z0-9\n/_.-]+?)[0-9\n]+[\n\b]', result, flags=re.M)
# match this group    '(                   )              '                   ^
# shortest possible   '                   ?               '          (multi-line
# at least one of     '                  +                '          string input)
# these characters    ' [A-Za-z0-9\n/_.-]                 '
# then, at least one  '                            +      '
# digit or newline    '                     [0-9\n]       '
# and ending with \n  '                             [\n\b]'
#   or end-of-string                     

# matches = ['nameof1stlink', 'nameof2ndlink', 'nameof3rdlink', 'nameof4thlin...\nk']

links = [link.replace('...\n', '') for link in matches]
# links = ['nameof1stlink', 'nameof2ndlink', 'nameof3rdlink', 'nameof4thlink']
```

I'm not sure what your links look like, but I assumed `[A-Za-z0-9/_.-]` (alphanumerics plus `/`, `_`, `.`, and `-`) covers all the standard parts of hyperlinks. And `\n` needs to be thrown somewhere in there to accommodate for multi-line entries. You can modify this character class depending on what you expect your links to look like.